# Getting a value from string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im new to objective-c
Lets assume I have a string such as this

`NSString* s = @"assets-library://asset/asset.MOV? id=100000009&amp;ext=MOV"`

how do I get the contents of the "ext=" ("MOV" in this case) out of it? How do I convert it to uppercase(so "mov" -> "MOV") in case it is not already so?

Comment: To clarify - do you simply want the contents of the "ext=" section at the end of the string? Also, convert *what* to upper case? (You might want to update your question, as it's a bit hard to tell what you're precisely after.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) componentsSeparatedByString method to decompose the string into an array as such:

```
NSString *sourceString = @"assets-library://asset/asset.MOV? id=100000009&amp;ext=MOV";
NSArray *stringChunks = [sourceString componentsSeparatedByString:@";ext="];
NSString *outString = [[stringChunks objectAtIndex:1] uppercaseString];
```

**UPDATE**

As I stated in my comment below, this is a kludge. (It'll fail if there's an argument after the "ext=") As such, here's a more robust implementation using NSURL. (Somewhat pointlessly it has to be said.) I've presumed that the space character in the original URL in your code is a typo, if not swap it out using the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString as per below.

```
// Create a URL based on a cleaned version of the input string.
NSString *sourceString = @"assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=100000009&amp;ext=MOV";
NSURL *sourceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[sourceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"]];
NSArray *pathComponents = [[sourceURL query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

// Create a dictionary of the key/value portions of the query string.
NSMutableDictionary *queryParameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString *component in pathComponents) {
[queryParameters setObject:[[component componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1]
                    forKey:[[component componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:0]];
}

// Fetch the contents of the "ext" key and force to uppercase.
// We should really check that objectForKey doesn't return nil, but this is just
// an example.
NSString *outString = [[queryParameters objectForKey:@"ext"] uppercaseString];

[queryParameters release];
```

Comment: this works but is slightly brittle. I would suggest this approach with a better separator - but that depends on knowing more about the structure of the string.

Comment: @Roger Nolan Have to agree - it feels like a bit of a kludge. (It'll fail if there's any additional query string args for example.) In an ideal world, some form of URL parsing would seem considerably more appropriate. Time for another dig. :-)

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS I've updated my answer with a more robust implementation, which I recommend you make use of.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into NSURL, which has explicit support for parsing URL strings.

Comment: You'll still need to manually process the data returned by the "query" method on the NSURL. (i.e.: NSURL unfortunately doesn't solve the issue as cleanly as you might suspect.)

Comment: @BJ Homer Incidentally, I've had a stab at a NSURL based solution in an update to my answer. I'd welcome improvements if you can think of any.